# post order general tree traversal in Python

Tags: python, tree, nodes, postorder

Is it possible to traverse a general tree (that is, a tree with multiple children) in a post order way using Python. Essentially, I want to traverse a tree like the one below from the lowest left going up in the tree and compare each node `.size` with its parents `.size` in terms of which one is largest, if the child is larger, I change the node `.max_size` to the child's `.size`. The root will always have the value of the largest in the tree stored in it.

[image]

My Question: is there a way to traverse a general tree in post order (for this example: `E, F, B, C, D, A`)? If so, what would be the way to do so?

Comment: The children would be an array instead of a general "left" and "right", but yes, you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you need the size stuff. You can do this:

```py
In [254]: class Node:
     ...:     def __init__(self, val: str):
     ...:         self.val = val
     ...:         self.children = []
     ...:

In [255]: A = Node('A')
In [256]: B = Node('B')
In [257]: C = Node('C')
In [258]: D = Node('D')
In [259]: E = Node('E')
In [260]: F = Node('F')
In [261]: A.children = [B,C,D]
In [262]: B.children = [E,F]
In [263]: root = A
# General post order but iterating over the children instead of doing left/right
In [264]: def post_order(root: Node):
     ...:     if root is not None:
     ...:         for child in root.children:
     ...:             post_order(child)
     ...:         print(root.val)
     ...:

In [265]: post_order(A)
E
F
B
C
D
A
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it **recursively**:

```
def updateNodeSize(node):
    if 'children' not in node:
        if 'size' in node:
            return node['size']
        return 0

    maxSize = 0
    for child in node['children']:
        maxSize = max(maxSize, updateNodeSize(child))
    node['size'] = maxSize
    return maxSize


updateNodeSize(root)
```